# GET Request to a url (to accept terms and conditions) returns the same page as the response body but works in POSTMAN

Tags: java, httprequest, postman

There is a page I need to access after accepting the Terms and Conditions in my crawler. However, even after using the url in the source code:

> `'/auth/submitterms.do?randomNum=' + randomNum`

the response body returned is the same terms and conditions page.
When I do the same in Postman it works fine and takes me to the next

`randomNum` is obtained using regex from the response body. I used the [cookieHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/CookieHandler.html) API to handle the session.

Code Snippet:
GET request to terms and conditions page:

```
connection = new URL(URL_NEXIS+"auth/ipmdelegate.do").openConnection();
    res = connection.getInputStream();
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(res)){
        response = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        System.out.println("Terms Page: \n"+response);
    }
```

Regex used to obtain the randomNum from the response:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("randomNum=[0-9].[0-9]*"); 
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
        randomNum = matcher.group().split("=")[1];
        System.out.println(randomNum.toString());
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Error: Could not accept terms and conditions.");
    }
```

GET request to URL which '*accepts*' the terms.

```
    System.out.println(URL_NEXIS + "auth/submitterms.do?randomNum=" + randomNum);
    redirect_page = URL_NEXIS + "auth/submitterms.do?randomNum=" + randomNum;
    connection = new URL(redirect_page).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection","keep-alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
    res = connection.getInputStream();
```

How can this be achieved and why is the same request behaving differently with Postman?

EDIT:
I used connection.setInstanceFollowRedirect(false); and was able to obtain a 302 response code. I can now see the location header and set-cookie variable. However, I think the cookieHandler api already handles the session.

Now when I try to send a GET request to the new Url from the location header, I get taken back to the terms and conditions page.

Comment: You could use *Fiddler* to monitor traffic when using postman vs. when using your code. This will help to understand the difference between the 2 cases.
https://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: Is there a difference between fiddler and Postman? From what I read they are both used to test (http) requests.

Comment: That's true. but Fiddler has another feature that Postman lacks, and that's recording all the traffic that goes out of your computer. SO, Fiddler can record and show you what is sent over the newtwork when you run your app, while postman can't. Kind'a like wireshark, but much more friendly and readable.

Comment: Ok, I used connection.setInstanceFollowRedirect(false); and was able to obtain a 302 response code. I guess Postman automatically follows redirects, but even now in the code, I get taken back to the terms and conditions page. I have edited my question to describe it.